# Calculate Mapping of Nearest Points of 2 matrices

Tags: algorithm, matlab, sift

I have two matrices A and B. Each of them has 2 columns having the coordinates of a point `( x , y )`.

I need to compute a `mapping of points from A to B` such that the points have least euclidean distance among them.

Essentially I am trying to emulate what sift does on images but will not carry out the steps that sift does for matching the points...

Thus for all points in A,  I compute euclidean distance with all points in B and then remove the mapping of 2 points which have the least distance. Then i continue to do this until A and B are both empty.

Could someone tell me what could be the most efficient way of doing this ?

EDIT

Can somebody help me ... The issue I am facing is that I need to compute all v/s all distances before selecting the minimum of them as the first mapping. Then I need to do this all over again making the computation really long...

Is there any way this can be done efficiently in MATLAB ?

Comment: I have asked very similar question before. The only difference - I had vectors and you have matrices. Anyway the solution should be very similar. Have a look: [Mapping 2 vectors - help to vectorize](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2142826/163080)

Comment: @yuk It is what I want ... but the data is not sorted and ofcourse they are matrices.... So can somebody suggest if there could be an inbuilt or a faster solution for it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to the Procrustes distance between the two different configurations of points? If so, Matlab has a built-in function that computes the smallest-norm transformation that brings the points into alignment (this is the Procrustes distance).

See [this documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/procrustes.html) for how to use it. If you don't have the Statistics Toolbox, then you should check the Matlab Central File Exchange first to see if anyone's written a non-toolbox version of the `procrustes()` function before seeking to write your own.