# In matlab finding similar elemants in vectors of unequal length within a tolerance

Tags: matlab, vector, compare

I have two column vectors of unequal lengths, `calib` (75 elements) and `nu` (1436 elements). I need to find the elements in `nu` that match the elements in `calib` to within a tolerance of 0.001, then perform operations on the resulting vector. All the elements are numbers not strings.

I thought intersect would be the way to go, but I don't see a way to introduce a tolerance. Also using a for loop with an absolute difference statement didn't seem to work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check my previous question, that might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142826/mapping-2-vectors-help-to-vectorize

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I'll have to try it and play around with it a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have another Matlabic (=matrix) way for this. I don't know how computationaly efficient this is, but Matlab should be good with matrices.

I'm assuming `size(nu) = [75,1]` and `size(calib) = [1436,1]`. The first step is making two big 1436x75 matrices (note the transpose):

```
calib_m = repmat(calib',size(nu))
nu_m = repmat(nu,size(calib'))
```

Then you can make another matrix `1436x75` that is the absolute difference of the above:

```
diff_m = abs(calib_m - nu_m)
```

Now find the smallest element in each column:

```
min_m = min(diff_m)
```

Then you can introduce your threshold and do a logical indexing (which should be fast):

```
ok_calib_elements = calib(min_m < THRESHOLD)
```

PS: I don't have Matlab here, so the code is not tested

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using a variation on this.

Comment: Glad to help. And glad that is works. Switched jobs from Matlab to Python and I sometimes miss some of Matlab's elegant loop-free coding.

Answer (score 3):

you can `round` one of you vectors to show only 0.001 accuracy and then use `ismember`. 
Or just use [ismemberf](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23294-ismemberf) - Floating-point ISMEMBER (i.e., with round-off tolerance) from the FEX.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. The matrix math got me where I needed to go. I don't know if there is a better way to do this, but here is my code that works:

```
% set tolerance for finding equal values in the data
find_tol = 1E-3; 

% make matrices of the data and clibration vectors
nu_m = repmat(nu',size(calib));
calib_m = repmat(calib,size(nu'));

% subtract the matrices
diff_m = calib_m - nu_m;

% find the minimum of each column within the tolerance and compute the
% average shift
find_min_nu = find(diff_m < find_tol & diff_m > -find_tol);
min_nu = diff_m(find_min_nu);
shift_nu = mean(min_nu);

% output calibrated values
calib_nu = nu + shift_nu;
```